# ProGuard configuration of greenrobot event bus

Tags: android, android-proguard, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I'm using eventbus into my application and it's working fine on debuge mode but not working on release APK.

Following code used for ProGuard configuration :

```
  -keepattributes *Annotation*
  -keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
   }
  -keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
```

> All my Subscribe-annotated methods are also public

**Logcat output :**

> Could not dispatch event: class
>   com.dhaval.example.model.entity.response.DashboardUnreadStoryResponse
>   to subscribing class class
>   com.dhaval.example.view.activity.MainActivity
>                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String com.dhaval.example.model.entity.Dashboard.b.a()' on
>   a null object reference
>                                                                      at com.dhaval.example.view.activity.MainActivity.b(SourceFile:150)
>                                                                      at com.dhaval.example.view.activity.MainActivity.onEventBusEvent(SourceFile:560)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at org.greenrobot.eventbus.c.a(SourceFile:485)
>                                                                      at org.greenrobot.eventbus.c.a(SourceFile:420)
>                                                                      at org.greenrobot.eventbus.c.a(SourceFile:397)
>                                                                      at org.greenrobot.eventbus.c.a(SourceFile:370)
>                                                                      at org.greenrobot.eventbus.c.d(SourceFile:251)
>                                                                      at com.dhaval.example.view.a.r$1.a(SourceFile:140)
>                                                                      at com.dhaval.example.view.a.r$1.a(SourceFile:130)
>                                                                      at com.dhaval.example.f.ap$2.a(SourceFile:90)
>                                                                      at com.dhaval.example.f.ap$2.a(SourceFile:85)
>                                                                      at com.dhaval.example.network.a$1.a_(SourceFile:101)
>                                                                      at rx.c.a.a_(SourceFile:134)
>                                                                      at rx.internal.operators.n$a.a(SourceFile:224)
>                                                                      at rx.a.b.b$b.run(SourceFile:107)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 07-14
>   11:39:43.640 16402-16402/com.dhaval.example D/EventBus: No subscribers
>   registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.j 07-14
>   11:39:43.657 16402-16402/com.dhaval.example
>   E/com.dhaval.example.view.a.r$1: Error in getResponse: Attempt to
>   invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   com.dhaval.example.model.entity.Dashboard.b.a()' on a null object
>   reference

Comment: Too me it doesn't seem to be eventbus related. It's just a NPE in your own model.entity.Dashboard class. May be you need to add that model.entity.Dashboard into proguard exceptions: -keep class model.entity.Dashboard.** { *; }

Comment: But this same code working into debug apk

Comment: Ok. may it is actually about greenrobot proguard configuration. Are you sure that you are applying those rules in you gradle file on release target? Also still check and add checks in your model.entity.Dashboard.b.a() that subscriber is not null - then it won't crash with NPE (but probably still won't work)

Comment: @shtolik Thank you for your quick reply :) I will check and revert back to you

Comment: @shtolik Thank you very much -keep class model.entity.Dashboard.** { *; } this code  worked for me

Comment: Good. I'll post it as an answer then:)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely sounds like proguard related, but probably not about eventbus, but about your own model.entity.Dashboard class. May be you need to add that model.entity.Dashboard into proguard exceptions:

```
-keep class model.entity.Dashboard.** { *; }
```